# Disable visual system beep on Karmic

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

Some programs are about to make me epileptic with excessive screen flashing/blinking (terminator etc.). In Ubuntu Hardy Heron I could solve the problem by unchecking System->Preferences->Sound->System Beep->Visual system beep. However on Karmic Koala there is no such option. I googled and found many solutions for turning off visual beep/bell. However nothing seems to work. So my question is that what is the exact alternative to disable Visual system beep on Karmic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is the module *pcspkr*

check if the module is loaded

```
 lsmod | grep pcspkr
```

if its loaded you can unload it with

```
 sudo rmmod pcspkr
```

if the annoying beeps disappear you have to blacklist the module:
Add the line

```
 blacklist pcspkr
```

to the file */etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf* if it exists. I do not know how ubuntu 9.04 or 9.10 do store the blacklisted modules.

Comment: ha I didn't read your last entry ;-)
in Ubuntu 10.4 the pcspkr mod is blacklisted per default and in my case it's not even installed

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had pcspkr disabled already, but probably wasn't. Also you pointed out pcsprk being blacklisted in the latest ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
gconf-editor &
```

and navigate to:

```
/apps/compiz/plugins/fade/screen0/options/visual_bell
/apps/compiz/plugins/fade/screen0/options/fullscreen_visual_bell
/apps/metacity/general/visual_bell_type
/apps/metacity/general/visual_bell
```

and see how they're set.

Also, some apps (e.g. `screen`) have their own controls for the visual bell.

Comment: Those are not set. So unfortunately no clue here :(. So far my only hope is to run older Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that my question was obsolete. I could repeat the problem with 9.04 and 9.10. With 8.04 and 10.04 there is no problem.